# Is there any way to host a public static website in GCP Cloud Storage and protect it using a username and password?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, web-hosting

GCP seems to allow you to delegate Cloud Storage authentication via IAM and that's great but you're only able to ever get a single file at a time using that method.

What I mean is, if I gave permissions to a user to have 'Storage Object Viewer' Role to a folder in a bucket, then a user would be able to browse to a single file (let's say an .html file) using https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucket-name/folder-name/filename and display that, but if that .html file contains .css or other files it needs the user to download then those all return 404 not found errors.

It seems that whatever token is obtained upon authentication is only valid for the retrieval of the single file that was requested before the token was created.

How does one host a static website, with some form of authentication in GCP Cloud Storage?

I did see a question similar to this asked over 5 years ago and thought GCP has changed considerably since then so that's why I'm re-asking.

Edit: Ok, let's assume I'm okay with public read-only access to bucket contents, and instead I'm going to focus on securing the GCP Cloud Functions which make the changes.

Now, I've enabled authentication on the GCP functions and used OAuth ID Token.  The issue is now CORS.  Any calls made to the GCP functions need a CORS access-control-allow-origin header, but that header does not get returned until AFTER the authentication.

Anybody know how to enable CORS on GCP Cloud Functions before any authentication takes place?

Thanks!

Comment: Have your users a Google account? I guess yes because you grant them on GCS.

Comment: Yes.  They have gmail accounts.

Comment: Just as an FYI.. I finally found the tidbit of documentation on GCP website highlighting that you should not apply IAM based permissions on Cloud Functions because the preflight OPTIONS request will get a 403 - forbidden.  That's the way it works even though CORS specification states that OPTIONS requests do not need an Authorization header and responses must be allowed without one.  In that same documentation, they state to use the Cloud Endpoints as a proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [host your static files on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files). The content is served for free!

In front of App Engine, you can [activate IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart).

Finally, grant your user (or groups, or Google Workspace domains) the role `IAP-Secured Web App User`.

Comment: Thank you Guillaume.  I didn't know that App Engine can serve content for free.  Either way, I decided to create a Cloud Endpoint which proxies the requests and provides IAM based security.

Comment: Cloud Endpoint is more designed for API. If you have issues, come back here and I will be able to help you more on APp Engine if you need.

Comment: You are correct in that it's for API and that's what I'm trying to do - protect the API calls from unauthorized calls.  According to GCP documentation (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) one option to allow CORS to work with authentication on Functions, is to use Cloud Endpoints proxy.  Unfortunately, the preflight calls fail if I add authentication to Endpoints proxy.  It's getting too complex than what I wanted (Needs Cloud Run to run Endpoints proxy container image).  I'm going to explore your proposed solution.  Are you referring to App Engine Basic?  or Flexible?

Comment: Standard, it's free! Flexible is expensive (always at least one instance up!)

Comment: Hi Guillaume,  I got it hosted in App Engine, thank you.  How do I protect the GCP Functions from being executed by non authorized users?  My issue still seems to be that preflight OPTIONS requests are being blocked due to CORS.

Comment: @Fadi, To protect functions from un authorized users you can use tokens as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#developers) -- And you can view an example and a description of handleing CORS requests [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests)

Comment: @Fadi Please Open a new issue if you require help with questions related to other topics, there you can provide more information on what you are stuck on and people will kindly try to help.

Comment: Thanks Diego but all the docs you've highlighted I've read and don't really solve the issue.  Thanks for sharing either way.  I'm going to have to get creative somehow.  I'm not going to pursue this further so no need to create a new question.